# Specifying secure CURLOPT_SSLVERSION in php.ini

Tags: php

I have a PHP app running on a php 7.0 Ubuntu server that uses a mix of custom code and and open source code.

I'd like to force the use of TLSv1.2 for all curl connections at the php.ini level.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: comand line curl `-tlsv1.2` php curl `curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);` at php.ini level, not an option

Comment: @smith thanks for the feedback. I suggest making that an answer so I can accept it. If you have any reference material to confirm that fact I'd love to see a link.

Comment: ild wait in case im completely wrong ;-) heres an alternative idea i just found https://serverfault.com/questions/737926/disabling-all-older-versions-of-ssl-in-apache-2-to-force-authentication-over-tls

Comment: as for reference material here are ALL the php.ini settings you do have: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php